# mark.js - URL Referrer highlighting with next/previous/clear functions

Tags: jquery, highlight, referrer

I would like to implement [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) highlighting so that search terms coming from my google custom search engine will be highlighted.  This can be done following the example provided for "URL Referrer highlighting".  I would like to be able to add next/previous and clear functions to help users click through the matches, as well as change the search criteria, as in the example for "Search bar with jump to matches".  I have been unable to get this to work... can anyone help with this?

Here is a working fiddle of the URL Referrer highlighting:
https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/axw5af8k/

I would like to incorporate Next | Previous | Clear buttons to allow users to work their way through the search matches.

There is a fiddle for the previous/next/clear functionality: https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/

The code they are using is:

```
    $(function() {

      // the input field
      var $input = $("input[type='search']"),
    // clear button
    $clearBtn = $("button[data-search='clear']"),
    // prev button
    $prevBtn = $("button[data-search='prev']"),
    // next button
    $nextBtn = $("button[data-search='next']"),
    // the context where to search
    $content = $(".content"),
    // jQuery object to save <mark> elements
    $results,
    // the class that will be appended to the current
    // focused element
    currentClass = "current",
    // top offset for the jump (the search bar)
    offsetTop = 50,
    // the current index of the focused element
    currentIndex = 0;

    /**
     * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
    */
    function jumpTo() {
        if ($results.length) {
          var position,
            $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
          $results.removeClass(currentClass);
          if ($current.length) {
            $current.addClass(currentClass);
            position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
            window.scrollTo(0, position);
          }
        }
      }

    /**
    * Searches for the entered keyword in the
    * specified context on input
    */
    $input.on("input", function() {
    var searchVal = this.value;
    $content.unmark({
    done: function() {
    $content.mark(searchVal, {
              separateWordSearch: true,
              done: function() {
                $results = $content.find("mark");
                currentIndex = 0;
                jumpTo();
              }
            });
          }
      });
    });

    /**
    * Clears the search
    */
    $clearBtn.on("click", function() {
    $content.unmark();
    $input.val("").focus();
      });

      /**
       * Next and previous search jump to
       */
      $nextBtn.add($prevBtn).on("click", function() {
        if ($results.length) {
          currentIndex += $(this).is($prevBtn) ? -1 : 1;
          if (currentIndex < 0) {
            currentIndex = $results.length - 1;
          }
          if (currentIndex > $results.length - 1) {
            currentIndex = 0;
          }
          jumpTo();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Ca n you add the code that might help us to help you out

Comment: @ankitverma  I've added links to fiddles and the code for the next/previous/clear functions to my question.  Thank you in advance for any help you could give me on this!